# Creating long randoms

Tags: c#, random, long-integer

So I have this

```
Random random1 = new Random();
int intrandom1 = random1.Next();
```

I want to put a long after the .Next. How do I do that? It only accepts ints.

Comment: I added Java, but not sure... what is OP's target

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Java's next is lowercase

Comment: @BeniBela : I dont know about any language where method/function/procedure begins with capital letter :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya could be a typo...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I know one: Pascal. But Pascal does not have a new operator. And it is case insensitive anyways

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number in long range, is this the way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651554/random-number-in-long-range-is-this-the-way)

Comment: Here comes someone from same area... now all problem solved :)

Comment: @BeniBela In Java it's `nextInt()` and `nextLong()` not next or Next.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: yes, but those start with a lowercase next

Answer (score 3):

First  idea: A long as 64 bit integer, is the combination of 2 32 bit integers, so you can use:

```
((long)random1.Next() << 32)  | random1.Next()
```

Or perhaps

```
((long)random1.Next() <<< 32)  | random1.Next()
```

if you use java (?) and need a unsigned shift

edit: does not look like Java. Java has random1.nextLong() for that. Perhaps C#? I do not know that

Comment: Java already has [`Random.nextLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextLong()) -which in facts works as you explain. +1 for the lateral thinking, anyway.

Comment: Java doesn't have a Next() method and nextInt() it is signed so every second number would have all 1s for the top bits.

Comment: Are you sure this will result in an even distribution along the number range?  I'm inclined to think that it will bias the results a bit, but I'm not a good enough mathematician to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be generated arbitrary long number by using a simple linked list. Just imagine that every node from list can store a number random generated, and a function can be read that list like an unitary number. Using an algorithm like that you can obtain an arbitrary long random number.