# C# Random(Long)

Tags: c#, random, int, long-integer, seed

I'm trying to generate a number based on a seed in C#. The only problem is that the seed is too big to be an int32. Is there a way I can use a long as the seed?

And yes, the seed MUST be a long.

Comment: Why do you need a long seed for a pseudorandom number?

Comment: @J0HN I'm calculating where slimes spawn in minecraft.

Comment: @user1599078 - Even if you use the Long that you've obtained, how can you guarantee that the psuedorandom number generated matches that of the Java implementation?

Comment: That's greek for me. Why do you think using long as seed will help you? +100500 for @keyboardP comment(sorry, SO allows only one upvote :))

Comment: @keyboardP I'm not sure what you mean but here is the algorithm:long RandomParameter = seed + (long)(x * x * 0x4c1906) + (long)(x * 0x5ac0db) + (long)(z * z) * 0x4307a7L + (long)(z * 0x5f24f) ^ 0x3ad8025f;
            Random rnd = new Random(Convert.ToInt32(RandomParameter));
            if (rnd.Next(10) == 0) return true; else return false;

Comment: Do you have the original RNG algorithm that Minecraft uses?

Comment: @MatthewWatson You mean before I ported it from Java? Random rnd = new Random(seed + 
                        (long) (xPosition * xPosition * 0x4c1906) + 
                        (long) (xPosition * 0x5ac0db) + 
                        (long) (zPosition * zPosition) * 0x4307a7L + 
                        (long) (zPosition * 0x5f24f) ^ 0x3ad8025f);
return rnd.nextInt(10) == 0;

Comment: Typical chicken-and-egg problem.  You now need a really good random number generator to produce a sufficiently random seed.  Starting a not-so-good random number generator with a really good seed is a complete waste of effort.

Use the System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider class.

Comment: @user1599078 - The Java version of `Random` will not necessarily be the same as the C# version. Therefore, it's very unlikely you're going to get the same output given the same input.

Comment: @HansPassant Mind linking to an example on how I'd use it?

Comment: @keyboardP I just checked, they have the same first parameter: the seed.

Comment: @user1599078 Unfortunately that doesn't guarantee the output will be the same. The number generated from the `Random` class (either in C# or Java), is not actually truly random in the mathematical sense. They take the seed and from that seed they perform various functions to give you what seems like a random number. The problem you have here is that both will give you a "random" number but that number won't necessarily be the same, even if the seed is the same, because they calculate that number differently.

Comment: @keyboardP That sucks, thanks for clarification though. I found somebody who wrote a Random function that acts like java's in python, I'll port it across now.

Comment: @user1599078 - Yup, as long as the internal implementation of the `Random` function matches up, you should get the same output. In that case, you don't even need the `Random` class and so you can create your own method that takes a `Long`.

Comment: You could look at the source for `java.lang.Random` and just convert it to C#; it's probably not too hard. The algorithm is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next%28int%29

Comment: The [MedallionRandom](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionUtilities/tree/master/MedallionRandom) NuGet package contains a port of Java's random number generator, which accepts a 64-bit seed.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone seeing this question today, .NET 6 and upwards provides [Random.NextInt64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextint64?view=net-6.0), which has the following overloads:

- `NextInt64()`

  - Returns a non-negative random integer.
- `NextInt64(Int64)`

  - Returns a non-negative random integer that is less than the specified maximum.
- `NextInt64(Int64, Int64)`

  - Returns a random integer that is within a specified range.

Comment: These methods generate random 64-bit numbers. The question is how do you initialize a `Random` instance using a 64-bit seed, which is unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a C# version of `Java.Util.Random` that I ported [from the Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next%28int%29).

The best thing to do is to write a Java program to generate a load of numbers and check that this C# version generates the same numbers.

```
public sealed class JavaRng
{
    public JavaRng(long seed)
    {
        _seed = (seed ^ LARGE_PRIME) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    }

    public int NextInt(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n", n, "n must be positive");

        if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
            return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

        int bits, val;

        do
        {
            bits = next(31);
            val = bits % n;
        } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
        return val;
    }

    private int next(int bits)
    {
        _seed = (_seed*LARGE_PRIME + SMALL_PRIME) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
        return (int) (((uint)_seed) >> (48 - bits));
    }

    private long _seed;

    private const long LARGE_PRIME = 0x5DEECE66DL;
    private const long SMALL_PRIME = 0xBL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the answer provided here by @Dyppl: [Random number in long range, is this the way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651554/random-number-in-long-range-is-this-the-way)

Put this function where it's accessible to the code that needs to generate the random number:

```
long LongRandom(long min, long max, Random rand) 
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[8];
    rand.NextBytes(buf);
    long longRand = BitConverter.ToInt64(buf, 0);
    return (Math.Abs(longRand % (max - min)) + min);
}
```

Then call the function like this:

```
long r = LongRandom(100000000000000000, 100000000000000050, new Random());
```

Comment: Per comments in link (and testing myself), this method does not work:  "Doesn't work properly. LongRandom(long.MinValue, long.MaxValue, new Random()), always returns -9223372036854775808. In any case, Math.Abs() destroys one bit, leaving you with 63 random bits. You can't provide a 64-bit random number if you only have 63 random bits."

Comment: These method generates a random 64-bit number. The question is how do you initialize a `Random` instance using a 64-bit seed, which is unrelated.