# Generate 10 digit random number in c# with random.Next

Tags: c#

I want to generate 10 digit random number but random.next function take int arguments that take 9 digit value How can i convert

[image]

Comment: You could create two 5-digit numbers and combine them..

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651554/random-number-in-long-range-is-this-the-way

Comment: also, try long int instead of double

Comment: please don't post code as screenshot. There are [several good reasons NOT to do it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `double barcode = rnd.NextDouble() * 9000000000.0 + 1000000000.0;`