# C# Generate random long number from double number

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert from python to C#

python:

```
rand = random.randint(0, 2 ** 50)
```

and here's what I did in C#

```
var value = Math.Pow(2, 50);
var result = random.Next(0, Convert.ToInt32(value));
```

I'm getting this error

```
Unhandled exception. System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Double value)
```

I wanted to generate from range 0 to value

Comment: Do you need the value to be an `int` *and* also range between 0 and 2^50? Can it be a `long`?

Comment: An `int` (`Int32`) can only hold a value up to near 2^31, so: yes, it will overflow a lot of the time if you ask for a value in the 2^50 range; a `long` can handle 2^63 - perhaps more useful?

Comment: instead of `Math.Pow(2, 50);` use `1L << 50` instead. In python use `1 << 50`

Comment: @harold sorry I edited my question it should be long

Comment: Then you may be interested in the answers to [Random number in long range, is this the way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6651554/555045)

Comment: `2 ^ 50 == 1125899906842624`. `int.MaxValue == 2147483647`.

Comment: You're going to need something like this: `long value = ((long)random.Next() << 18) ^ (long)random.Next();`

Answer (score 3):

In C#, an `int` is 32 bits.   You have 2^50, that needs 50 bits. It will always be too large.

You could use `Convert.ToInt64(value)`, that would fit but Random only returns an Int32. So it is kind of pointless.

I would suggest using 2^30. You're not going to get any more range. That 50 looks  kind of arbitrary anyway.

```
var value = Math.Pow(2, 30);
```

On second thought, just use

```
var result = random.Next();  // returns 0 .. Int32.MaxValue-1
```

and remove everything with `value`.

Comment: But the required I need is 50

Comment: Then look up the linked question, with NextBytes(). Als, be sure you need 50 bits _random_ , not 50 bits _unique_.